# Handling views for multiple controllers in spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have started a spring project with have multiple controllers. Is there any way to group the vies for each controller in a separate folder inside WEB-INF? Let me explain:

When I have one controller only, I have one folder WEB-INF/jsp, which are referenced by this block in my spring-servlet.xml (or whatever name it was):

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.horariolivre.controller.PrimaryController"/>
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
```

In this project, I want have at least four folder, one for each controller, in the way I can create mappings like that:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="acesso")
public class PrimaryController {

    @Autowired
    private SessaoHome sessao;

    @Autowired
    private UsuarioHome usuario;

    @RequestMapping(value="login")
    public ModelAndView login() {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.setViewName("login");
        return mav;
    }
...
}
```

and use paths like this: acesso/login.

Each folder I want create in the WEb-INF will have the mapping name of one controller, and each JSP placed in this folders will have the mapping name of the methods from controller.

Someone knows any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do works perfectly well.
If you have a folder under jsp named `acesso` and inside it you have a file named `login.jsp`
the following code

```
@RequestMapping(value="login")
    public ModelAndView login() {
        return new ModelAndView("accesso/login");
    }
```

will forward control to login.jsp

Comment: Ok, that works partially. But I have a problem with the resource files (css, js, etc) included in the page acesso/login.jsp. First time I open it, all works fine, but when I reach it from other page (after a logout, by example), none of this resources files are read, as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22624247/inconsistency-in-the-mapping-of-resources-in-a-spring-project