# Use of the mvc:resources causes an 404 error in my Spring application

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

In my spring app, I am following the tip from this article:

http://www.java-allandsundry.com/2012/10/spring-mvc-static-resource-handling.html

to map my resources files (css, js, etc).

The problem is when I put this code in my spring-servlet.xml file, I receive an 404 error when I try run the application (none page is even displayed):

```
    <mvc:resources mapping="/bootstrap/**" location="/bootstrap/" /> 
    <mvc:resources mapping="/extras/**" location="/extras/" /> 
    <mvc:resources mapping="/jquery/**" location="/jquery/" />
```

this is my **web.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>HorarioLivre2</display-name>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>acesso/login.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>HorarioLivre2</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HorarioLivre2</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Just for the record, if I remove the 3 lines above from my *-servlet.xml file, I only can access my application if I replace this line:

```
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
```

by that one:

```
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
```

Someone knows how configure correctly the resource mapping with mvc:resources?

**my *-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd">

        <context:component-scan base-package="com.horariolivre"/>
        <mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>
        <mvc:resources location="/bootstrap/" mapping="/bootstrap/**" />
        <mvc:resources location="/extras/" mapping="/extras/**" />
        <mvc:resources location="/jquery/" mapping="/jquery/**" />

            <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
                <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
                <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
                <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
            </bean>

        <context:annotation-config>
            <bean class="com.horariolivre.resources.HibernateConfig">
            </bean>
        </context:annotation-config>

        <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
</beans>
```

How i include the resources in my JSP file:

```
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="<c:out value="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="<c:out value="/extras/css/signin.css"/>" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Append your location patterns with `**` is well (e.g. `/boostrap/**`)

Comment: don't work. what's more strange to me is the why i can't even access my application; it was more natural to me if only the resources can't be reached in case of some problem with this configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below works for me within my application.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="controllers, email"></context:component-scan>
<mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>
<mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/static/**" />
    //defined within the dispatcher servlet xml file

    <security:http use-expressions="true">
            <security:intercept-url pattern="/static/**" access="permitAll" />
            <security:intercept-url pattern="/images/**" access="permitAll" />
    //defined within the security-context.xml file
```

JSP Display of Images

```
<img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/css/images/spring-logo.jpg"
        alt="" title="" border="0">
```

Yours could be

```
<img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/extras/image.jpg"
        alt="" title="" border="0">
```

Comment: this doesn't work for me, since I am not using spring-security in this application.  But one thing I don't get: do you really place the mvc:resources in your web.xml? what option you append to your <web-app> tag to make this work?

Comment: Apologies, I meant the DispatcherServlet config xml files. I've added a bit more to it. Does the app start without the resource tags?

Comment: ok, with your suggestion I now can reach the pages from my application, but the resources are sill unreachable. I update my question to include my revised *-servlet.xml and some lines from my JSP files where I include the resources.

Comment: You're not getting the application context. I've edited my answer to show how I display images within a JSP page.